# How to accommodate external auth service with istio through mesh configuration with Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-aks, istio-gateway

Can you please help me with below two queries?
We need to add new changes to implement authorization policy in Istio gateway, This should be done during installation or upgrade of Istio via Azure DevOps pipeline.

To implement this via Azure Pipeline, we need some inputs to understand how can we accommodate below changes in our pipeline.

1. How to accommodate external auth service with istio through mesh configuration with Azure DevOps yaml file(servicemesh yaml)?
2. Apply Authorization Policy in istio-system namespace
   We have an YAML with 'kind: AuthorizationPolicy' for Istio. How can we call this file or apply this configuration during installation of Istio?

We still didn't find any documentation to perform the above changes in our Azure DevOps pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [**Kubernetes extension**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tsuyoshiushio.k8s-endpoint) for Azure Pipelines that should be able to meet your demands in Azure Pipelines.

This extension provides the tasks to execute [**`istioctl`**](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/commands/istioctl/), [**`kubectl`**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/kubectl/) and [**`helm`**](https://v2.helm.sh/docs/helm/#helm) commands in pipelines.

You can install this extension to your Azure DevOps organization (or collection), then reference its [**`README.md`**](https://github.com/TsuyoshiUshio/KubernetesTask) to set up your pipeline in Azure DevOps.

Comment: We had already the pipeline available and able to implement the Istio gateway through pipeline. We need to do some customization to Istio gateway to configure an external authorization policy. We were basically checking how can we call this authorization yaml during the installation of Istio.

Comment: @VarunKM, Looking at the **`README.md`** of that extension, it seems has provided the task for authorization Istio with Kubernetes.